# How can i put pieces of text into a grid-like layout without using tables?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, formatting

I have a variable amount of 1 word text items being outputted from a mysql database query.

In order to make them presentable and spread in an aesthetic manner in the div, i figured i could put them into a table, this way no matter how many outputs i have, they will be sorted and organized.

I figured i can use php to pop the output into an array, and based on the number of elements in the array i can modify the formatting accordingly using control statements.

However upon doing some research i've heard it's bad to use tables for formatting because i should keep content and layout separate.

Does that really apply in this case? If so, how could i make a desirable layout in a div when i dont know whether there will be 5, 10, or 20 elements?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're actually looking to tabulate data, which is what tables are for (not the same as pure layout, where tables are merely used for spacing and alignment without there being any tabulated structure to the data therein).

Comment: Tables are not evil as many think, they are meant for tabular data representation and that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: tables are PERFECT for formatting **DATA**. That's what they're for. tables were abused to lay out entire pages, which is where the "don't use for layout" comes from.

Comment: This page's layout uses tables =o( \*dies a little inside\*

Comment: there's no problem using tables if you're actually showing data. back in the day people used to format their entire site using tables to get the correct look, which is what is looked down upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to put your query into a table.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            $mysqli->close();
        }

    $values = $mysqli->query("YOUR SELECT GOES HERE");
    $cols = 3;
    $i =1;
    echo "<table>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
while($row = $values->fetch_assoc())
    { 

    if (is_int($i / $cols))
        {
            echo "<td >".PHP_EOL;
            //what ever you want to include goes here
            echo "</td>".PHP_EOL;
            echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
            echo "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
        }
        else
            {
                echo "<td >".PHP_EOL;
                //what ever you want to include goes here
                echo "</td>".PHP_EOL;
            }
            $i++;
    }
        echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL; 
        echo "</table>".PHP_EOL;
```

you can set the amount of rows with the $cols variable

Comment: Instead of that I better suggest an iterator that is able put the logic to create the columns out of the loop.

Comment: I actually use an iterator interface to do mine, just thought i would start him off with the basics

Answer (score 3):

If your dataset is something like a long list of single words or short phrases (like a list of categories), lists are the most appropriate markup.  Using the `columns` property, you can get something that somewhat resembles a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/b8Vw5/ (shows 3 lists:  short, medium, and very long)

```
ul {
    -webkit-columns: 3; /* I think I got all of the prefixes here... */
    -moz-columns: 3;
    -o-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When people say "using tables for formatting is bad", they're referring to the ancient technique of using empty table cells with set width/height as "padding", rather than using CSS. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the `<table>` element.

That said, if yours is a list of words, it would make more sense semantically to place them in a list. To that end, try this CSS:

```
#mylist {list-style:none}
#mylist>li {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Then have your HTML output be:

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>Word</li>
  <li>Another</li>
  <li>Derp</li>
  <li>Blah</li>
  <li>UNICORNS!</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Never knew we can use `display:inline-block;`

Comment: Check Cross browser inline block [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Comment: @Sithu Are you really still using hacks to support IE6 and below? `inline-block` has been widely supported for a [very long time](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block)

Comment: @Kolink, I not hacking IE6, but IE7. According to my experience, it does not work in IE7.